# How to ssh without needing a password

Tags: python, ssh, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I just want to run a python file on raspberry pi and use terminal code ssh. So, I don't want type password to do that. What should I do?

Comment: what type of system are you initiating the SSH with? You'll want some sort of "SSH authentication agent"

Comment: You might want to have a look at this blog entry (and its follow-ups) https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/148032481829/ssh-security-and-usability-part-1

Comment: Use public/private keys instead or as well as password login.  You only need an authentication agent if you then use a password for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use public key authentication without protecting the private key with a password. On your management computer execute these commands:

```
mngmt ~$ mkdir -m 700 ~/.ssh
mngmt ~$ ssh-keygen -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa -t ecdsa -b 521
```

This will give you a keypair `id_ecdsa` as private key and `id_ecdsa.pub` as public key in `~/.ssh/`. Now on your client RasPi login as a user, for example **pi**, and create also:

```
rpi ~$ mkdir -m 700 /home/pi/.ssh
```

and copy `id_ecdsa.pub` from the management computer to  `home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the client RasPi. Check with a simple ssh from your management computer if it works by executing `/bin/hostname` on the client. That should return the hostname of the RasPi:

```
mngmt ~$ ssh pi@raspberrypi hostname
raspberrypi
mngmt ~$
```

This is a save authentication method as long as nobody else does get access to the private key file `id_ecdsa`. Everyone owning this file have access to your clients so please pay attention to it.