# Authentication with Public Key and Password Option

Tags: ssh, login

Is it possible to allow the user to use Public Key and Password to authenticate to their ssh account (Have both options enabled rather just one or the other)?

If it possible, how to do so?

Comment: Yes - in fact this is the default unless you change it.

Comment: @Milliways thanks so I can use both Password and Public Key for authentication?

Comment: yes - in fact that's what the `yes` in his comment means

Comment: @JaromandaX Also how do I do it? (i.e. which sshd config would I need to modify)

Comment: don't change any config ... just add authorized_keys ... as milliways explained *this is the default unless you change it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments password and public key authentication are enabled by default. If you enable ssh and know the name resp. ip address of the RasPi you can just connect to it with user **pi** and password **raspberry**. You can also use public key authentication out of the box. Just install public and private keys as described for ssh. You can find an example at [Unable to SSH after securing Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/90545/79866).

Answer (score 1):

While out of the box the Pi is using passwords, and public keys in the sense of host keys, I think what he is asking is if you can continue to use password authentication AFTER you setup user public key authentication.

Once you do so, then there is no need for the less secure password authentication, and the whole point of setting that up is to not need to stop and enter a password, which can be brute force attacked to begin with.

So, there is no need to do such a thing.

Check out "SSH Mastery" by Michael W. Lucas for more detail.

Comment: The *need* is a rather subjective thing to start with. There are situations conceivable where a user wants to set up public key authentication for convenience only and not security (as in, simplified log in process, typing no password); but still keeping password auth. to log in from another machine w/o the keyfile. Not judging whether this is a wise thing to do or not, just saying there might be a *need*.

Comment: Given that password protection is an inferior level of protection, it would completely nonsensical, and thus by definition would not be "needed".   Logic.  :)

Comment: Old but I thought I would comment on the debate of having both.  Using some tools, and several computers, I don't know how to make SSH work, so a failed back to the id/password, only to find its no longer active.  Do have to pass around my private key to enable other computers to login? The most secure application is non-functional.